# Ajax heartbeat does not finish until concurrent ajax request completes?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My load balancer closes idle connections after 60 seconds and it sometimes takes over 60 seconds to run `download_files.php`.

I would like to work around this issue by sending a heartbeat every 45 seconds to make sure the connection stays active

```
var heartbeatTimer = 0;
heartbeatTimer = setInterval(function () {      
    var heartbeatXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    heartbeatXhr.open('GET', 'heartbeat.php', true);
    heartbeatXhr.send();

}, 45*1000);        


$.ajax({
    url: "download_files.php"
});

clearInterval(heartbeatTimer);
```

The problem is that all the heartbeats begin every 45 seconds but don't finish until the `download_files.php` script completes.

[image]

How do I make sure the heartbeats finish immediately after the request for them is made (I'm using mod_php)?

Also, how do I make sure the first heartbeat begins after 45 seconds? In the above example it starts at 0 seconds, for example if it takes 30 seconds to run `download_files.php` I would like for the heartbeat to not run once.

Comment: Does `download_files` and `heartbeat` use sessions?

Comment: yah - the contents of `heartbeat.php` are `<?php start_session(); ?>` and `download_files.php` begins with `start_session()`

Comment: Try calling [`session_write_close()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) when you no longer need session variables, i.e. after the last session variable you use.

Comment: I don't think this will work because even with keepalive the connection is not reused while the request is still running, so the heartbeats will use a different connection and the original connection will still be considered idle by the LB.

Comment: @AndreKR Hey Andre - after some trial and error, I believe you are correct... do you have any alternatives?

Comment: Hm, `echo ' '; flush();` in `download_files.php` during processing and  trim the result in JS maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple ajax calls and too many concurrent processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652054/multiple-ajax-calls-and-too-many-concurrent-processes)