# Multiple ajax calls and too many concurrent processes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 3 ajax calls on a set interval so they update users notification at regular intervals behind the scenes. I had to disable this recently as it caused too many concurrent processes and killed the site on our shared hosting.

I like the functionality of the below but I am wondering if I can do this in a more economic way like nest them in the call backs. So one finishes before the next starts.

The question is, what is the best way to do multiple ajax calls at regular intervals?

```
 setInterval(function() {
        // check who is online
        $(".whosOnline").load("ajax/whosOnline.php", function(data) {});
        // check for new messages
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/message-count.php',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                $(".MessageCountContainer").html(data);
            }
        });
        // check for new notifications
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/notification-count.php',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                $(".NotificationCountContainer").html(data);
            }
        });
    }, 15000);
```

Comment: You can set async to false in the ajax and then they will run concurrently, I'm not sure if it won't cause the page to freeze while it's running though unfortunately.

Comment: I suggest you to look into WebSocket...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the next ajax request in the callback of the previous one, like this :

```
setInterval(function() {
        // check who is online
        $(".whosOnline").load("ajax/whosOnline.php", function(data) {
            // check for new messages
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/message-count.php',
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".MessageCountContainer").html(data);
                    // check for new notifications
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajax/notification-count.php',
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $(".NotificationCountContainer").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });     
        });
}, 15000);
```

But, I think it is easier and more efficient, to join together the three call on the server side and put the result in a json format.
Then client side you can use it like this :

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/get-all-notification.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $(".MessageCountContainer").html(data.MessageCountContainer);
            $(".NotificationCountContainer").html(data.NotificationCountContainer);             
        }
    });
}, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var timeout = null;
var _notifications = true;
// check who is online
var a = function() {
  return $(".whosOnline").load(url, function(data) {}).promise()
};
// check for new messages
var b = function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $(".MessageCountContainer").html(data);
    }
  })
};
// check for new notifications
var c = function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $(".NotificationCountContainer").html(data);
    }
  })
};

var count = 0;

var notifications = function notifications() {    
  return $.when(a()).then(b).then(c).then(function() {
    ++count;
    console.log(count);
    // stop `notifications`
    // if (count === 5) {
    //  clearTimeout(timeout);
    //  _notifications = false;
    // };
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      if (_notifications !== false) {
          notifications()
      };
    }, 15000)
  })    
};

notifications();
```

```js
var timeout = 0;
var _notifications = true;

var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/6a76aa9d2921350c9d53/raw/49fbc054731540fa68b565e398d3574fde7366e9/abc.txt";

    // check who is online
    var a = function() {
      return $(".whosOnline").load(url, function(data) {}).promise()
    };
    // check for new messages
    var b = function() {
      return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
          $(".MessageCountContainer").html(data);
        }
      })
    };
    // check for new notifications
    var c = function() {
      return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
          $(".NotificationCountContainer").html(data);
        }
      })
    };

    var count = 0;
    var notifications = function notifications() {

      return $.when(a()).then(b).then(c).then(function() {
        ++count;
        console.log(count);
         if (count === 5) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          _notifications = false;
         };
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          if (_notifications !== false) {
              notifications()
          };
        }, 15000)
      })

    };
    notifications();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="whosOnline"></div>
<div class="MessageCountContainer"></div>
<div class="NotificationCountContainer"></div>
```